# How to call named templates based on a variable?

Tags: xslt, fxsl

I don't know if it's possible, but I'm wondering how to do it...

Let's say we have the following XSL:

```
<xsl:template name="foo">
  Bla bla bla
</xsl:template>
...
<xsl:template name="bar">
  Bla bla bla
</xsl:template>
...
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:if test="$templateName='foo'">
    <xsl:call-template name="foo"/>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="$templateName='bar'">
    <xsl:call-template name="bar"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Is it possible to change the XSL to read something like...

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="$templateName"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is <strike>not possible</strike> not directly possible. The calling convention is:

```
<xsl:call-template name="QName" />
```

Where a [QName is defined as](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#NT-QName):

```
QName ::= PrefixedName | UnprefixedName

PrefixedName   ::= Prefix ':' LocalPart
UnprefixedName ::= LocalPart

Prefix         ::= NCName
LocalPart      ::= NCName
```

Basically this boils down to "characters only, no expressions". As the other answers highlight, there *are* in fact ways to do something equivalent, but the straightforward approach/naïve approach will not work.

Comment: Ah, but there is an ugly hack to work around this - see my answer.

Comment: @Tomalak This has been possible (although in a different syntactic form) for almost 8 years :)  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 13):

It's not possible exactly as you describe, but if you want to be able to choose a template at run-time based on some value you set elsewhere, there is a trick to do that. The idea is to have your named template also match a node with a corresponding name in a distinct mode (so that it doesn't mess up your normal transformation), and then match on that. For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... xmlns:t="urn:templates">

  <!-- Any compliant XSLT processor must allow and ignore any elements 
       not from XSLT namespace that are immediate children of root element -->
  <t:templates>
    <t:foo/>
    <t:bar/>
  </t:templates>

  <!-- document('') is the executing XSLT stylesheet -->     
  <xsl:variable name="templates" select="document('')//t:templates" />

  <xsl:template name="foo" match="t:foo" mode="call-template">
    Bla bla bla
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="bar" match="t:foo" mode="call-template">
    Bla bla bla
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="template-name" select="..." />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$templates/t:*[local-name() = $template-name]"
                         mode="call-template"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Note that you can use `<xsl:with-param>` in `<xsl:apply-templates>`, so you can do everything with this that you could do with a plain `<xsl:call-template>`.

Also, the code above is somewhat lengthier than you might need because it tries to avoid using any XSLT extensions. If your processor supports `exslt:node-set()`, then you can just generate nodes directly using `<xsl:element>`, and use `node-set()` to convert the resulting tree fragment to a plain node to match against, without the need for `document('')` hack.

For more information, see [FXSL](http://fxsl.sourceforge.net/articles/FuncProg/0.html#Starting_point) - it's a functional programming library for XSLT that is based on this concept.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone's future reference:

Here is a working example based on Pavel Minaev's answer. No original thought on my part. ;-) I switched it to use msxml:node-set as he described (more or less) so that it works in .NET.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" version="1.0">
    <xsl:variable name="templates">
        <templates>
            <foo />
            <bar />
        </templates>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template name="foo" match="foo" mode="call-template">
        <FooElement />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="bar" match="bar" mode="call-template">
        <BarElement />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Root>
            <xsl:variable name="template-name">bar</xsl:variable> <!-- Change this to foo to get the other template. -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($templates)/*/*[local-name() = $template-name]" mode="call-template" />
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: The links below were updated to point to web.archive.org -- unfortunately, IDEALLIANCE has made all *Exteme Markup Languages* conference proceedings unavailable...
In due time, I will find a more permanent place for these two articles.

---

This is implemented in [**FXSL**](http://fxsl.sf.net).

There are good explanations of the main principles of FXSL.

See the following two articles:

"**Functional programming in XSLT using the FXSL library**" (for XSLT 1.0), (PDF) at:

http://web.archive.org/web/20070710091236/http://www.idealliance.org/papers/extreme/proceedings/xslfo-pdf/2003/Novatchev01/EML2003Novatchev01.pdf

(HTML) at:

http://conferences.idealliance.org/extreme/html/2003/Novatchev01/EML2003Novatchev01.html

"**Higher-Order Functional Programming with XSLT 2.0 and FXSL**" (PDF) at:

http://web.archive.org/web/20070222111927/http://www.idealliance.org/papers/extreme/proceedings/xslfo-pdf/2006/Novatchev01/EML2006Novatchev01.pdf

(HTML) at:
http://conferences.idealliance.org/extreme/html/2006/Novatchev01/EML2006Novatchev01.html

Using FXSL I have been able to solve easily and elegantly many problems, that seem "impossible for XSLT". One can find a lot of examples [**here**](http://dnovatchev.spaces.live.com/Blog/).

Comment: Unfortunately, both of your links don't work, can you re-check them? Maybe they are bound to a valid session or something, I keep getting "Page Not Found" errors.

Comment: @Tomalak: Thank you for letting me know. I will investigate. There is something strange this morning: facebook is unaccessible and twitter seems hacked ...

Comment: Yes, Twitter is down for me, too. Luckily I have no Facebook account, that's one less addiction. ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak: Sorry, I cannot make the links appear as they should. Do you know any workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think I had more or less the same problem as you. I had an "outer" template and wanted to call a different "inner" template depending on some variable set at run-time. I found your question by Googling for a way to have a dynamic `<xsl:call-template>`. I solved it by using `<xsl:apply-templates>` instead, as follows.

The input XML (generated at run-time) contains something along the lines of:

```
<template name="template_name_1"/>
```

The XSL in the "outer" template has:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="template"/>
```

*(The `select="template"` in this apply-templates refers to the `<template>` tag in the input XML)*

And finally the "inner" template, which I wanted to include as a result of the value of the `name` attribute in my XML, looks like:

```
<xsl:template match="template[@name='template_name_1']">
    <!-- XSL / XHTML goes here -->
</xsl:template>
```

*(Again, the `match="template[@name='xyz']"` refers to the previous `select="template"` and in turn to the `<template>` tag and its `name` attribute in the input XML)*

In this way I can have a dynamically "called" template simply by controlled from my input XML.

This might not be the same problem as you are trying to solve but I think it's pretty close, and much simpler than the FSXL solutions mentioned elsewhere on this page.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?:

```html
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

      <xsl:template match="xsl:template[@name='foo']" name="foo">
    Bla bla bla foo
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="xsl:template[@name='bar']" name="bar">
    Bla bla bla bar
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="templateName" select="'bar'"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('')/*/xsl:template[@name=$templateName]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('')/*/xsl:template[@name='foo']"/>
      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can simplify a "call" of the template using a variable similarly as described in an earlier contribution:

```html
<xsl:variable name="templates" select="document('')/*/xsl:template"/> 

<xsl:apply-templates select="$templates[@name=$templateName]"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$templates[@name='foo']"/>
```

Note that optional `<xsl:with-param>` can be used as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Pavel, @Dimitre for the excellent answers. Here is another working example that basically recycles @Pavel's approach for future reference...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  

  <xsl:variable name="templates">
    <xsl:for-each select="('foo','bar')">
      <xsl:element name="{.}"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  
  <xsl:template name="foo" match="foo" mode="call-template">
    Foo foo foo
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template name="bar" match="bar" mode="call-template">
    Bar bar bar
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
  
    <xsl:for-each select="('bar','foo','foo','bar')">
      <xsl:variable name="template-name" select="." />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$templates/*[local-name() = $template-name]"  mode="call-template"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    
    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```